# align portion of label to right

Tags: alignment, label

I have a label that needs to have a portion of it aligned to the right.

For example if this is the text box:

|left.........right|

If there is no easy way to align right... I have an idea, but I'm not sure it's possible but here it is:

I could calculate the width of the right string by adding the width of the pixels of each character, a fixed width font is ideal. With this I could calculate amount of spaces I need to insert to get the text all the way to the right.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without knowledge which OS/toolkit you're referring to??

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width:200px">
  Left
  <div style="float:right;">Right</div>
</div>
```